# Im trying to access a N dimensional vector but I get into infinite recursion

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to access a n-dimensional vector but somehow (empty? '()) keeps returning false.

;; access n dimensional vectors
;; (access-nd vector a-list-of-numbers) -> element
;; (access-nd (vector (vector 'x 'y) 'a 'b)) 0 1 ) -> x

```
(define (access-nd avector . alist)
  (cond
    ((and (not(empty? alist)) (vector? avector))
     (vector-ref (access-nd avector (rest alist)) (first alist)))
    (else avector)))
```

Please Help.

Edit: CORRECTED CODE

```
(define (access-nd avector . alist)
  (cond
    ((and (not(empty? alist)) (vector? avector))
     (apply access-nd (vector-ref avector  (first alist)) (rest alist)))
    (else avector)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, that one line should read:

```
     (vector-ref (apply access-nd avector (rest alist)) (first alist)))
```

Without the "apply", `alist` will never be empty.  Here's why:

In the definition of `access-nd` the `alist` parameter is an optional parameters list; it's separated with a dot from normal positional parameters.  This means `access-nd` can be called with 1-n parameters.  Any parameters after the first one are collected to a list and bound to `alist`. For example, a call like

```
(access-nd v 1 2 3)
```

will cause `alist` to be bound to the list `(1 2 3)`.  Similarly, this call in your original code:

```
(access-nd avector (rest alist))
```

will cause `alist` to be bound to a list with one element.  That's why `alist` will never be empty.

Scheme's `apply`, on the other hand, takes a list of arguments as the last parameter and calls the function as if they were passed to it in the normal way.

Comment: Could you tell me why that is?

Comment: Edited my reply with hopefully enough detail to understand what is going on.